Unable to deploy azure application gateway
I have site lets call it test.air.be and i have two azure functions and they are part of different backend pools. I am using one listener on port 443 with the certificate.
Now i want to do path based routing so that:

if the request comes for /abc/functionapp1/anyfunction then it should be routed to first functionapp1 backend pool
if the request comes for /def/functionapp2/anyfunction then it
should be routed to second functionapp2 backend pool

Also do note that i think i need to use rewrite option as well as i would like to forward the request to the particular function in end as you know functions url have /api/functionname in their url.
When i try to hit the url of an Application gateway, URL path-based routing always redirect to default backend pool always and it always go to one backend pool and not the other backend pool.
My path based routing section is given below:
path rule 1:
Path: /abc/functionapp1/function1*
Target name: function1
backendsetting: default
backend target: functionapp1bp

path rule 2:
Path: /abc/functionapp2/function2*
Target name: function2
backendsetting: default
backend target: functionapp2bp



Unable to deploy azure application gateway

When a request is routed, the full URL path is sent to the backend pool. If the requested resources are located on a different path, you will need to configure either a URL Rewrite Rule or override the backend path in your backend settings.

URL path-based routing always redirect to default backend pool always and it always go to one backend pool and not the other backend pool.

Ensure that the path-based routing rules are in the correct order to forward the traffic. also verify that the path patterns in your path-based routing rules are correct; they should match the URL path that you want to route to the specific backend pool.

To forward traffic based on path, you need to add the required path mappings in the backend targets in routing rule configuration of the respective backend pool for those paths. Follow the Configure apps for more details.

Note: For both the v1 and v2 Application gateway SKUs, rules are processed in the order they are listed in the portal. The best practice when you create path rules is to have the least specific path (the ones with wildcards) at the end. If wildcards are on the top, then they take priority even if there's a more specific match in subsequent path rules.

Reference :
Advanced routing capabilities using Application Gateway Rewrite Rules by Andy Doyle
Path based routing in Azure Application Gateway with Azure WebApps by Dominique St-Amand
Rewrite HTTP headers and URL with Azure Application Gateway | Microsoft Learn
